# On hover of a link, have a line run left to right underneath

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a line to animate left to right underneath the hovered link in a list. Right now, nothing happens when hovered.

https://jsfiddle.net/60vufuv5/1/

This is an example of getting it to work on just a single link but I didn't have any luck in the fiddle above: https://jsfiddle.net/4bgkcoaq/

```
<nav class="contact-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="name_2"><a href="mailto:xxx@gmail.com">xxx@gmail.com</a><div class="slider"></div></span></li>
    <li>+1-347-419-7751</li>
  </ul>
</nav>


li name_2:hover > .slider {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Martin Ah sorry. I was just wondering how can I get that slider to work in the first fiddle. In the list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an initial width of 0 and also a transparent bottom border on your element.  Then on hover, expand that width to 100% and give the bottom border a color.

Something like:

```
.name_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0%;
}

.name_2:hover{
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60vufuv5/5/)

Comment: How come the border goes all the way to the end of `contact-nav` and not just to the end of the `<span>`? https://jsfiddle.net/60vufuv5/6/

Answer (score 1):

this may help you.this is an alternative way using `html`, `css` with four lines of `jquery`.just copy and try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .myclass{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: orange;
        position: absolute;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="myclass">
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myclass").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({left:400});
        });
    });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```